# How to dock open files in tab format on top in Jedit

Tags: jedit

Currently my open files display in a drop down menu in Jedit, and I would like to change the display to tabs.

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin named [BufferTabs](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?BufferTabs).You can install it from the plugin manager. You have to enable it in your plugin manager to be on by default.

You can configure the docking location of Plugins under the global Options menu item in the top dropdown menu.

Comment: Two things, BufferTabs is on by default since some versions. And the position of the Tabs is not configured in the Global Options, but in the Plugin Options of the BufferTabs plugin. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In jEdit click on

Plugin Manager -> "click Install" tab

This will list the available packages to install

-- Select BufferTabs to install tab options